# How to manage hadoop logs using amabri?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to ambari and I want to overwrite retention policies defined in hadoop log4j.properties file using ambari.

I wanted to use custom appender to log hadoop logs.
I have added this appender to {HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/log4j.properties file and updated respective env.sh files to use my custom appender.

Now when I restart all services from ambari dashboard ambari reverts all my changes from log4j.properties.

Please suggest how to overwrite log4j and other env.sh files in ambari.

From where ambari picks up the installation files and restores it while reinstalling all components.

Comment: You better ask this question in Hortonworks forum. There is a separate section for Ambari there http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/forum/ambari/

Comment: I got the solution for above question on this link.
http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hdfs-audit-loggerinfoconsole/